# Use different env configs per environment | Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, variables, config, environment

**In Angular, I want to use different env configs per environment.**

That means, if I for example deploy to the dev Enviroment, I want the Angular App to use the Dev Variables, and if I deploy to Prod I want Angular to use the prod Variables.

Is there a way to do that? For Example create a file with all the variables and then Angular just has to look in which environmnent it is in and choose the right variable.

Comment: Check this -> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a new typescript file  in project root directory, same directory where pacakage.json file exist,
lets say you make a file with name set-env.ts
put this code into the file

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs';
// Configure Angular `environment.ts` file path
const targetPath = './src/environments/environment.ts';
const targetPathProd = './src/environments/environment.prod.ts';
const envConfigFile = `export const environment = {
   production: false,
   serverURL: 'https://devenviroment.com/api',
   someOtherProperty: 'response'
};
`;
const envProdConfigFile = `export const environment = {
   production: true,
   serverURL: 'https://serverurlproduction.com/api',
   someOtherProperty: 'value'
};
`;
console.log('The file `environment.ts` will be written with the following content: \n');
console.log(envConfigFile);
writeFile(targetPath, envConfigFile, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`Angular environment.ts file generated correctly at ${targetPath} \n`);
  }
});
writeFile(targetPathProd, envProdConfigFile, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`Angular environment.prod.ts file generated correctly at ${targetPath} \n`);
  }
});
```

Now add this line to package.json file inside scripts tag

```
"config-env": "ts-node set-env.ts",
"build": "ng build"
```

Now when you are building your project you can simply use this command

```
npm run config-env & npm run build
```

npm run config-env command will overwrite your environment files with configurations that you have written in set-env.ts

Answer (score 0):

Jignesh Patel, from TheCodeHub, writes it so well -
https://www.thecodehubs.com/how-to-configure-multiple-environments-in-angular/

How to use environment variables in code

---

src/environments/environments.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: '/website-backend'
};
```

...component.ts

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export class CalculatorConfigServiceService {
    apiUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/calculator`

...
}
```